# Problem with a cloudflared website running on linux

Tags: cloudflare

Launched cloudflared with parameters:

```
cloudflared tunnel --url http://localhost:8080
```

And when I entered it, this error appeared:

```
error="Group ID 1000 is not between ping group 1 to 0"
2023-11-07T12:37:25Z WRN ICMP proxy feature is disabled error="cannot create ICMPv4 proxy: Group ID 1000 is not between ping group 1 to 0 nor ICMPv6 proxy: socket: permission denied"
```

I didn't pay attention and went to the site and some scripts broke